# pythonのグローバル変数を関数内で操作して保持する方法を教えてください

Tags: python

```
my_property = 1000
farm= []

def monster_merchant1():
    global my_property
    global farm
    cat = 100
    rat = 50
    lizard = 200
    dog = 300
    feeble_doragon = 1000


    print("商人が来ました")
    print("なにか御入り用ですか？")
    print("1.ネズミ：{0}.2.ネコ:{1}.3.トカゲ:{2}.4.番犬:{3}.5.弱弱しいドラゴン:{4}".format(rat,cat,lizard,dog,feeble_doragon))
    print("数字を入力してください:")

    number =input()
    if number ==1:
       my_property = my_property - rat
       farm.append("ネズミ")
    elif number ==2:
        my_property = my_property -cat
        farm.append("ネコ")
    elif number ==3:
        my_property = my_property - lizard
        farm.append("トカゲ")
    elif number ==4:
        my_property = my_property - dog
        farm.append("番犬")
    elif number ==5:
        my_property = my_property -feeble_doragon
        farm.append("弱弱しいドラゴン")

    print("あなたの農場:"),
    print(farm)
    print("貴方の資産："),
    print(my_property)


monster_merchant1()
```

このコードを描いたとき、最後のprint文で表示する二つの変数（farm,my_property）に関数内での操作の結果を反映させたいのですが、実際にはリストfarmには何も入っておらず、my_propertyは初期値の1000のままです.

どうすれば関数内での操作を反映できるでしょうか。初心者なので要領を得ない質問かもしれませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `feeble_doragon = 1000` と `print("商人が来ました")`の間(他の部分でも同じ)インデントを保っていますか？

Comment: はい。関数内では　インデントは保てていると思います。

Comment: ここに挙げられたコードではインデントが無くなっていました。（つまり行頭に改行の状態。）　こちらで試してみたところでは期待するように動作すると思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()`の返す型が文字列なので(python 3.xの場合)、if文であてはまるものがなくて、変数が変更されず初期の値がそのまま出ているんだと思います。入力を数値に変換する処理をどこかに入れると良いでしょう。

例:

```
number = int(input())
```

余談: python 2.xでは元のコードでも期待通りに動作するでしょう。2.xの`input()`は`eval(raw_input(prompt))`と同等なので、文字列がevalされて数値になるからです。

Comment: 出来ました！ありがとうございます！！！！！！！